# Unresolved reference to task result data on Firestore Listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I have this method that attempts to retrieve documents from firestore, but for some reason i get an error: " unresolved reference : data " in task.result.data, what could i have missed?

[image]

```
  import android.util.Log
  import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val docRef = db.collection("Cocab").document("Keys").collection("allkeys")

    // do something
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val document = task.result
            if (document != null) {
                Log.d("mate", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + task.result.data)
            } else {
                Log.d("mate", "No such document")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("mate", "get failed with ", task.exception)
        }
    }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.d("mate", "get failed with ", exception)
        }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about the problem. It's not clear to me what you mean by "unable to access data()".  If you are getting an error message, please copy the message exactly as you see it into the question, and be sure to point out which line it's on.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I have edited my answer with the error.

Comment: So what are you trying to accomplish here?  Your `docRef` is not a document reference.  It's a collection reference.  When you call get() on it the task result is going to be a QuerySnapshot with zero or more documents - **all** of the documents in that collection.  You can't assume there just one document, and the API won't let you do that.  With a QuerySnapshot, you are expected to iterate the results.